# How to calculate the angle of intersection of the diagonals of a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, quadrilateral

Let's consider two triangles ABC and DEF.
[image]
All the six angles of both the triangles are known.
And, BC = DE. Now, I form a quadrilateral by combining these triangles such that the side BC or DE is now one of the diagonals of the quadrilateral.

So, what's the angle of intersection of the diagonals of this quadrilateral?

I think this question must be solvable because the shape of both the triangles is fixed and thus the shape of the quadrilateral is also fixed so the angle of intersection of the triangles must also remain fixed.

If both of these triangles are right angled triangles, then the quadrilateral formed by these triangles taking their hypotenuses as diagonal is a cyclic quadrilateral and the angle of intersection can easily be calculated. This is how I got this question, what if the triangles aren't right angled then how I will calculate the angle of intersection.

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: More specifically: I'm not sure there's enough information here to say anything particularly useful, other than that the angle is in fact determined by the information given.

Comment: There is nothing truly special about your triangle set-up. You are given a general quadrilateral and you know the lengths of its sides and its angles. (You do know the length of one of its diagonals, but this — and the length of the other diagonal — follows immediately from the law of cosines.)

Comment: The only reasonable solution I see, by the way, is to use vectors and use the dot product to find the angle between the vectors of the two diagonals.